# Updating Dell Bios Silently Through SCCM

Tags: deployment, dell, sccm, bios, firmware

I am trying to run an upgrade script through SCCM for Dell Bios Firmware.

I need it to run silently without an immediate reboot.

When I push the script, the upgrade runs and logs as successful with an exit code of 2 - Reboot Required.

However, when a user manually reboots after the process either immediately afterwards or at End of Business, the bios flash does not run during the post sequence and no upgrade is performed.

This is the script: E7470-06.exe /s /FORCEIT /l=c:\logs\E7470-06.log

Any help as to why it doesn't complete the upgrade after reboot would be greatly appreciated.

Log Capture:

```
***BIOS flash started on 10/12/2016 at 13:50:29***
Command: C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\5x\E7440A18.exe /s /FORCEIT /l=c:\logs\E7440A18.log

A13 INSTALLED (Dell System Latitude E7440)
- System BIOS : A13
- Embedded Controller : A10
- Legacy Video OROM : 2178.V.15
- Legacy RAID OROM : 12.7.0.1936
- Intel Management Engine (VPro) Update : 9.5.14.1724


A18 UPDATE (Dell System Latitude E7440)
- System BIOS : A18
- Embedded Controller : A14
- Gigabit Ethernet : 0.6
- Legacy Video OROM : 2178.V.15
- Legacy RAID OROM : 12.7.0.1936
- Intel Management Engine (VPro) Update : 9.5.14.1724
- Intel Management Engine (Non-VPro) Update : 9.5.14.1724
- ACPI OS support : 0.0.0.1
- Intel AntiTheft : 3.0.0.18

Exit Code = 2 (Reboot Required)
***BIOS flash finished at 10/12/2016 at 13:50:40***
```

Comment: [Reboot is required to complete installation](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/w/wiki/3462.dup-bios-updates)

Comment: We do reboot , it's just not immediate. We have the user's reboot on a break, but it doesnt complete the process on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to manually upgrade the BIOS?

If you enable Bitlocker, you need to suspend Bitlocker first.

If the BIOS has a password, you need to specify the password.

```
E7470-06.exe /s /r /p=YOURNEWPASSWORD /FORCEIT /l=c:\Logs\E7470-06.log
```

Note:

CCTK – Recommend brushing up on it [here](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN294541/en)

[Dell Bios Command Line syntax](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/w/wiki/3461.legacy-bios-updates)